# How to use custom pan control in google map v3 from outside of map

Tags: php

I am using google map v3 api and i want customize means i want to reposition pan control outside of map [image: I am using google map v3 api and i want customize]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply, you can't do this in css / javascript if `google maps api` doesn't have any function to do this so just forgot about this in google maps why you shouldn't try other maps provider like this [mapbox](http://www.mapbox.com)

Answer (score 2):

I think using css it solve 1. Position:absolute; 2. top:-30px; 3. zindex:999;